# Set GridView columnWidth to wrap_content in xml

Tags: android, android-gridview

I have a `GridView` containing `ImageView` all of the same size.
Each `ImageView` has its width set to `wrap_content`, so that I can support multiple screen resolutions by picking the correct version of my `Drawable` resource.

I can't find a way to automatically set the column size of my `GridView` to the `ImageView`'s width.

This can probably be done programmatically using

```
mGridView.setColumnsWidth(mImageView.getWidth());
```

but I can't find a way to do it using only XML. Does such way exists?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this-

```
android:columnWidth="50dp"
```

Here you can give the dimension.

Comment: `wrap_content` is a not valid value

Comment: The way to do by xml is this only, giving this attribute in your Gridview.